# How to make the attached pdf file be downloadable when sending email with go/smtp?

Tags: go, email, pdf, smtp, base64

I try to send the email containing pdf file by using Go and smtp.office365.com.

I found the following page and can send the email with pdf file.

https://zetcode.com/golang/email-smtp/

However, the pdf file is encoded as base64 as shown in the attached image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4mpV.png)

Is there any solution to make the attached pdf file be downloadable just like ordinary mail(attaching file with gmail, outlook, etc.)?

Here is the Go code that I used.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/base64"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/smtp"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type loginAuth struct {
    username, password string
}

type Mail struct {
    Sender  string
    To      []string
    Subject string
    Body    string
}

// LoginAuth is used for smtp login auth
func LoginAuth(username, password string) smtp.Auth {
    return &loginAuth{username, password}
}

func (a *loginAuth) Start(server *smtp.ServerInfo) (string, []byte, error) {
    return "LOGIN", []byte(a.username), nil
}

func (a *loginAuth) Next(fromServer []byte, more bool) ([]byte, error) {
    if more {
        switch string(fromServer) {
        case "Username:":
            return []byte(a.username), nil
        case "Password:":
            return []byte(a.password), nil
        default:
            return nil, errors.New("Unknown from server")
        }
    }
    return nil, nil
}

func BuildMail(mail Mail, filename string) []byte {

    var buf bytes.Buffer

    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("From: %s\r\n", mail.Sender))
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("To: %s\r\n", strings.Join(mail.To, ";")))
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Subject: %s\r\n", mail.Subject))

    boundary := "my-boundary-779"
    buf.WriteString("MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n")
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=%s\n", boundary))

    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\r\n--%s\r\n", boundary))
    buf.WriteString("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n")
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\r\n%s", mail.Body))

    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\r\n--%s\r\n", boundary))
    buf.WriteString("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n")
    buf.WriteString("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n")
    buf.WriteString("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" + filename + "\r\n")
    buf.WriteString("Content-ID: <" + filename + ">\r\n\r\n")

    data := readFile(filename)

    b := make([]byte, base64.StdEncoding.EncodedLen(len(data)))
    base64.StdEncoding.Encode(b, data)
    buf.Write(b)
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("\r\n--%s", boundary))
    buf.WriteString("--")

    return buf.Bytes()
}

func readFile(fileName string) []byte {

    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return data
}

func Mail_send(sender string, sender_pwd string, server string, port int, to []string, headerSubject string, body string, filename string) {
    auth := LoginAuth(sender, sender_pwd)

    request := Mail{
        Sender:  sender,
        To:      to,
        Subject: headerSubject,
        Body:    body,
    }

    data := BuildMail(request, filename)

    err := smtp.SendMail(server+":"+strconv.Itoa(port), auth, sender, to, data)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error")
        return
    }
    log.Fatalln("Success")
}

func main() {
    server := "smtp.office365.com"
    port := 587
    sender := "my email"
    password := "my pwd"
    receiver := []string{"EmailIWantToSend@gmail.com"}
    title := "TEST\r\n"
    body := "test\r\n"
    attach_filename := "report.pdf"

    Mail_send(sender, password, server, port, receiver, title, body, attach_filename)
}
```

Here is the email that I received.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=my-boundary-779

--my-boundary-779
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"

test

--my-boundary-779
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report.pdf
Content-ID: <report.pdf>

JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAyIDAgUgovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwIFI+PgplbmRvYmoKNCAwIG9iago8PC9GaWx0ZXIgL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlIC9MZW5ndGggMTcyMz4+CnN0cmVhbQp4AZyaS2/dRg+G9/4Vs/w
... // I omit since base64 string is too long.
AgbiAKMDAwMDAwMzc0NSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA0MDUzIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDQxNjYgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAovU2l6ZSAxMQovUm9vdCAxMCAwIFIKL0luZm8gOSAwIFIKPj4Kc3RhcnR4cmVmCjQyNjQKJSVFT0YK
--my-boundary-779--
```

I want that the email receiver can download the attached pdf file directly, not the base64 string.

Comment: Please provide relevant text information as linked image but instead include the text properly formatted in your question. Apart from that - this is pdf, so don't use text/plain but instead applicatiion/pdf as content-type. The base64 encoding in the source code is normal, if done properly applications should transparently decode is because of the given `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`. Unfortunately no more help can be done since you don't provide actual code you use and so it is impossible to recommend what you did wrong in your specific code.

Comment: Dear Ullrich/ Thank you for your comment. I attached the code that I used. If you don't mind, please give me more details about your comment: "his is pdf, so don't use text/plain but instead applicatiion/pdf as content-type".

Comment: Does your subject end with a new line? (Or does `fmt.Springtf` introduce another new line?) Gmail doesn't consider `MIME-Version: 1.0` to be part of the mail headers. So it seems like you have an empty line before that. Instead of posting a screenshot, show us the "raw message" (click on the three dots in the upper right corner and then on "Show original").

Comment: Please make a complete example which creates the exact mal you have problems with. As  Kasper Etter noted - there is likely some newline in the result which does not belong there and which might be introduced by a newline in the subject you gave as argument.

Comment: Dear Etter and Ullrich/ I would appreciate it if you could forgive my inexperience. I added related information. If it is not enough, please let me know. I will add asap.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. You still copied only the body of the received email, though. The full message includes the header fields, such as `To:`, `From:`, `Subject:`, and the like. As explained earlier, you get the full/raw message in Gmail by clicking on the three dots in the upper right corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, you break your message headers with an empty line. A complete message consists of header fields and a body separated by an empty line, which looks as follows:

```http
From: Alice <alice@example.org>
To: Bob <bob@example.com>
Cc: Carol <carol@example.com>
Subject: A simple example message
Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2022 16:44:37 +0200
Message-ID: <unique-identifier@example.org>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Hello Bob,

I think we should switch our roles.
How about you contact me from now on?

Best regards,
Alice
```

You, however, end the subject with a newline (`title := "TEST\r\n"`) and then write another newline (`buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Subject: %s\r\n", mail.Subject))`). As a consequence, `MIME-Version: 1.0` is considered to be part of the message body instead of the header. Try it again without the newline at the end of `title`. And as Steffen Ullrich noted, you should replace `Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"` with `Content-Type: application/pdf` when you send a PDF. (The charset is also not necessary.)

Comment: Dear Etter/ Thanks a lot!! It works!! Your (and also Ullrich) comment has been of great help! Have a nice day :)

Comment: @bakgu I’m glad to hear that your problem has been resolved. Please accept my answer, then.

Comment: @Etter I did! However, I cannot vote that your answer is useful since I didn't reach 15 reputation.